# endnote indentation equal to bibliography

Tags: indentation, natbib, typography, endnotes

I am using `endnote` to place my footnotes as endnotes at the end of my book and `natbib` for my bibliography. As such, i want both list to have the same indentation.

I know I can set the indentation of endnotes as such:

```
\def\enoteformat{\rightskip=0pt \leftskip=0pt \parindent=1.8em
\leavevmode\llap{\makeenmark}}
```

but wonder how to get the settings used in `natbib`.

MWE:

```
% endnotes
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
% bibliography
\usepackage[super, longnamesfirst, sort&compress]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}

\begin{document}

\endnote{testendnote} and \citep{testcite}

% the endnotes
\theendnotes
% the bibliography
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\begin{thebibliography}{99} 
\bibitem{testcite} Bloggs, J., The Journal of Stuff, 2012 
\end{thebibliography} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I update the question with a MWE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading your comment I think you want it like this:

[image]

It can be obtained with:

```
\def\enoteformat{\rightskip=0pt \leftskip=21pt \parindent=-11pt
\leavevmode\llap{\makeenmark}\hspace*{11pt}}
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

% endnotes
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
% bibliography
\usepackage[super, longnamesfirst, sort&compress]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}

\def\enoteformat{\rightskip=0pt \leftskip=21pt \parindent=-11pt
\leavevmode\llap{\makeenmark}\hspace*{11pt}}

\begin{document}

\endnote{testendnote some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text  some text some text} and \citep{testcite}

% the endnotes
\theendnotes
% the bibliography
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{testcite} Bloggs, J., The Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Journal of Stuff, 2012
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

---

### Original answer

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

It can be obtained with

```
\def\enoteformat{\rightskip=0pt \leftskip=10pt \parindent=0pt
\leavevmode\llap{\makeenmark}}
```

Comment: Something like this, but what i'm exactly looking for is how to vertically align the "testendnote ..." and "Blogs ..." by changing the distance between the label "1" and the text following after it.

Comment: @rubenbaetens I've edited the question. See if now it is OK.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, thanks.